# Prove $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a} \geq \frac{c+a}{c+b} + \frac{a+b}{a+c} + \frac{b+c}{b+a}$

Tags: inequality

Prove that $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a} \geq \frac{c+a}{c+b} + \frac{a+b}{a+c} + \frac{b+c}{b+a}$ with a,b,c > 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}-3=\left(\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{a}-2\right)+\left(\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}-\dfrac{b}{a}-1\right)=\dfrac{(a-b)^2}{ab}+\dfrac{(a-c)(b-c)}{ac}\tag{1}$$

> Similarly, $$\dfrac{a+c}{b+c}+\dfrac{b+c}{a+b}+\dfrac{a+b}{a+c}-3=\dfrac{(a-b)^2}{(b+c)(a+b)}+\dfrac{(a-c)(b-c)}{(b+c)(a+c)}\tag{2}$$
>  As $a,b,c >0$, it is obvious that $(1)$ is greater than $(2)$ as without loss of generality, we can set $c=\max{\{a,b,c\}}$ or $c=\min{\{a,b,c\}}$

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why you think about that ??, it's beautiful.

Comment: about the way you invent the hint you give me? how you did, or it's just  your experience?

Comment: @N.Drake Please check the edits.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, i can do it myself with your first hint. I just wonder how can you creat the hint

Comment: @N.Drake That's why I added the solution within spoilers.

Comment: @downvoter why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Show ${a\over b} +{b\over c} +{c\over a}  \ge {c+a\over c+b}  + {a+b\over a+c}    +{b+c\over b+a}$
But this is the same as (1) a/b+b/c+c/a >= (2) avg(c,a)/avg(c,b)+avg(a,b)/avg(a,c)+avg(b,c)/avg(b,a)  . Thus it is sufficient to show a (mean preserving) spread of the inputs increases avg{a/b,b/c,c/a} . This is easily verified.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Could you please add more details to make it more clear?

Comment: By the way there is a great deal of difference between a verification and a proof. For example, consider the inequality $a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab$. Plugging different $a,b$ values, we can see that it is true. However, proof of this inequality is established by $a^2+b^2 -2ab=(a-b)^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: @Roby5 It is easily shown using multivariable calculus.

Comment: As of now this answer is a mere comment. If it is so **easy**, would you mind showing your steps? By the way, why did you downvote my answer?